# Typescript export default function

Tags: javascript, typescript, default

My current typescript version is 1.6.2 and we compile it to ECMA 5. I am new to TypeScript so please be understanding. These are the imported library typings.

redux-thunk.d.ts:

```
    declare module "redux-thunk" {
    import { Middleware, Dispatch } from 'redux';

    export interface Thunk extends Middleware { }

    export interface ThunkInterface {
        <T>(dispatch: Dispatch, getState?: () => T): any;
    }

    var thunk: Thunk;

    export default thunk;
}
```

In app.ts:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

console.log(thunk);
```

I am getting undefined. This is the code taken from: 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/redux-thunk/redux-thunk-tests.ts (7 and 16 lines)

I've got the same problem with all libraries that uses default import in typescript.

EDIT:
@Steve Fenton I am using npm to do the job for me. I've just noticed that the problem is with Typescript compiler. When I create typescript file with export default function I get for example:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = {
    nextQuestion: nextQuestion,
};
```

Notice `exports.default`

When I look into `redux-thunk.js` file downloaded from npm there is:

```
exports.__esModule = true;
exports['default'] = thunkMiddleware;

function thunkMiddleware(_ref) {
    var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
    var getState = _ref.getState;

    return function (next) {
        return function (action) {
            return typeof action === 'function' ? action(dispatch, getState) : next(action);
        };
    };
}

module.exports = exports['default'];
```

Notice `module.exports = exports['default'];`

If I take redux-thunk typings into Babel compiler I get the results with `exports['default']` style.

The most important part is that when I replace `export['default']`  style to `exports.default`  style in  `redux-thunk.js` then everything works. Is this a problem with my compiler?

Comment: With ES5 you can use `import thunk = require('redux-thunk')`. If you want to use `import` either `import * as thunk from 'redux-thunk'` or import {thunk} from 'redux-thunk'

Comment: @Rik What is the difference between import thunk from "redux-thunk"; and import * as thunk from "redux-thunk"; ? if there is only one export default shouldn't both return the same?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why it won't work. Maybe it's ES6 syntax. I am not so much of a typescript guru.

Comment: How are you including the actual JavaScript file for redux-think in your application?

Comment: @SteveFenton see edit please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My friend just got the answer on github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-155216760

> ahejlsberg answer: It appears the "redux-logger" module was transpiled
>   with Babel. When Babel transpiles a module whose only export is an
>   export default it injects a module.exports = exports["default"]; into
>   the generated code, causing the exported object to become the function
>   itself (instead of a module object that has the function as the
>   default property). When paired with the _interopRequireDefault magic
>   that Babel generates for imports the net effect is that a fake module
>   object with a default property is created and the function can now be
>   accessed as _reduxLogger2.default.
>
> TypeScript doesn't do any of this magic (see here for more details).
>   In order for TypeScript to consume the module you need to change the
>   redux-logger.d.ts declaration file to actually reflect what is going
>   on